# Unable to create filesystem on new partition - Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, mount, amazon-ec2

I created a new partition /dev/xvda1p1 on linux amazon ami.
After that i am unable to create a filesystem.

What is the issue?

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/xvda1: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3ace0183

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1p1               1          14      112423+  83  Linux

# mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvda1p1
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Could not stat /dev/xvda1p1 --- No such file or directory

The device apparently does not exist; did you specify it correctly?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tricks:

- `udevadm trigger` to make udev look for new devices and create /dev/xvda1p1
- `blockdev --rereadpt /dev/xvda1` to explicitly tell it to re-read partition table on it
- `mknod /dev/xvda1p1 b ${some_number} ${some_number2}` manually. ${some_number} is probably the same as in /dev/xvda1 and ${some_number2} is like /dev/xvda1's, but +1.
- Finally, you can `losetup -o ${some_offset} /dev/loop0 /dev/xbda1` and use /dev/loop0. ${some_offset} is probably 8225280.

Comment: great, i will try this, but what is the root cause of problem?

Comment: That the /dev/xbda1p1 file does not exist. Normally kernel should detect partitions on a device and udev should create nodes in /dev/ for them.

Comment: partprobe for informing kernel is also not working in my case

Comment: # blockdev --rereadpt /dev/xvda1
BLKRRPART: Invalid argument